# Azure B2C Forgot password is not showing on Xamarin.Forms UWP app

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a Xamarin.Forms app using MSAL.NET + ADB2C.
After I updated the **Page Layout Version** of the **Forgot Password Page** to the latest version (2.1.17 - no custom page), UWP stopped working and it only shows a blank Page when the user navigates to the Forget Password.

[image: UWP Blank Page]

Using version 2.1.16 everything works as expected. Is this a bug in MSAL.NET library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with the layout itself. UWP WebView may not work if there's an issue in the content. Since [System Browser is not supported in UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-web-browsers?source=recommendations#at-a-glance) the workaround here is to go back to the working layout. I'm reaching the B2C team about this and will come back later with an update.

Comment: Hello, the product team is requesting a link to the userflow using the 2.1.17 page layout and also possible endpoints being called from it. Can you share those? If you need to share such information privately then we need to move to another medium since I don't think SO supports private messaging.

Comment: Kindly reminder.